# Проверка пользователя: на странице ли он?

Tags: php, javascript

Здравствуйте.

Интересует следующее:

Например, я просто зашёл на сайт, не залогиниваясь. Нужно в то время, пока я на сайте, чтобы выдало `alert(0)`, а если уже ушёл с сайта и потом через n минут/часов вернулся, больше этого не выдавало.

Или же проще. Вконтакте окошки чёрные вылезают тогда, когда юзер на сайте, а если он уже ушёл и потом пришёл, они не вылезают.

Подскажите, как подойти к данной задаче?

Comment: Что значит ушел с сайта?

Comment: Значит, он там был, а теперь больше нет. XD

Comment: уточните значение слова "ушел". Пользователь закрыл страницу сайта ил свернул браузер и пошел пить пиво? Ответ @knes не проливает свет на этот вопрос, к сожалению.

Comment: @iKuzko, закрыл страницу сайта :)

Comment: В таком случае ответ с COOKIES весьма хорош :) 

Вопросы о Вконтакте и фамилия Дуров... заставляет задуматься :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[COOKIES](http://www.w3schools.com/js/js_cookies.asp)

Comment: Мм, а как например узнавать, сейчас ли юзер на сайте или нет?

Comment: Без залогинивания вы сможете лишь узнать, что КТО-ТО у вас на сайте. Не более того. Нужна авторизация, по-любому. Другое дело, ее тоже можно запихать в кукисы, чтобы она происходила единожды.

Comment: @knes, а если вот так:

>> Или же проще. Вконтакте окошки чёрные вылезают тогда, когда юзер на сайте, а если он уже ушёл и потом пришёл, они не вылезают.

Comment: @Руслан Дуров, это знает лишь @Павел Дуров )))

Comment: @Руслан_Дуров, вообще-то, войти вконтакт без авторизации нельзя по определению. Это так, для справки.

Comment: Простите, но я вот по ссылке http://vk.com/id85941569 спокойно просмотрел информацию. При том, что я этого человека не знаю. Я попал к нему через подписчиков другого человека, который был в подписчиках у третьего и т.д. Так же я просмотрел фотографии и сообщения на стене у людей. При этом я не логинился на сайте. Боюсь ваше утверждение не корректно.

Comment: Оно некорректно сформулировано, согласен. Войти для каких-то активных действий. Просмотр - пассивное действие. при этом, максимум, вы будете отображаться как "аноним".

Answer (score 2):

Вконтакте node.js`овский [socket.io](http://socket.io)